# MATLAB: Parsing numbers out of string

Tags: matlab, parsing

I have an array of filenames acquired by the `x = dir('*.TXT')` function:

```
JFK_1_1.TXT
JFK_12_12.TXT
JFK_123_123.TXT
```

The filenames have 2 numbers which are preceded by the underscore character.  Is there a string parsing function that can parse the out the numbers based on the `_` and `.` delimiter?

The goal is to create an array from the numbers in the filenames:

```
A = [1 1; 12 12; 123 123];
```

Comment: `>> mymat=textscan([x.name],'%q%f%f','Delimiter','_');`
`>> flipud([mymat{2},mymat{3}])`

Comment: or `>> str2double(fliplr(reshape(regexp([x.name],'\d+','match'),2,[])).')`

Answer (score 4):

If `x=dir;` and `y={x.name};` gives you those filenames then:

```
A = regexp(y,'JFK_(\d*)_(\d*).TXT','tokens'); %general pattern would be: '.*_(\d*)_(\d*).*'
```

Now you have the required elements in `A`. Rest remaining is shaping them into the desired form.

```
A = [A{:}];
A = str2double(vertcat(A{:}));
```

Comment: The final A is not the desired matrix, you need to flip it.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness There is no such issue. I have double checked it

Comment: Downvote is welcome. Please let me know what is missing so that I may improve it. Thanks!

Comment: @Sardam OP's desired matrix is `A = [1 1; 12 12; 123 123];`, yours is `A = [123 123; 12 12; 1 1];`. Also OP is asking for a `textscan` solution.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness 1). There is no Sardam here. 2) It is giving exactly [`A = [1 1; 12 12; 123 123];`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SFlO.png) 3) Nowhere in the question, the constraint of using textscan is mentioned.

Comment: 1) Typo. 2) See [here](https://imgur.com/a/UFmxU9L). 3) You read OP's comment to ThP answer since you commented on it previously.

Comment: Additionally, your regex pattern is incorrect. You should use `+` as a quantifier and not `*`. If there was a text file which did not include numbers, such as `JFK__`, your regexp would output an empty match too.

Comment: The empty regex match would therefore result in `NaN`s in your final matrix.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness The OP already has that *array of filenames*. If there is a text file which doesn't include numbers is not the OP's case and so + and * don't matter here. The OP didn't anywhere constrained himself to the use of textscan in any comment. The OP said he was trying to manipulate that textscan answer to avoid looping. Please don't assume things. Thanks

Comment: He is getting the array of filenames from the dir command. Using your solution, if other files are present in the folder, would result in a wrong matrix.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness His array of filenames is shown to be in order. Presence of other files is another assumption. Please don't assume. If you doubt, ask the OP.

Comment: I am just pointing out the limitation of your solution if other files are present in the folder. OP should be aware of this.

Comment: Also the `.` should be escaped if you are matching a literal dot. Won't make a difference here, but still worth mentioning.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`textscan`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html).

```
C = textscan(str, 'JFK_%d_%d.txt')
```

Should give you a cell array with the numbers if you replace `str` with the file name.

EDIT:
You can do it without for loop if you wish -

```
l = dir('JFK*.txt');  
C = arrayfun(@(x) textscan(x.name, 'JFK_%d_%d.txt'), l)
```

Comment: You may need to loop over all such filenames

Comment: Agreed.  I have been tinkering with the textscan in attempt to avoid looping.   Seeking an elegant one-liner with textscan.  Would be nice if textscan could process an array of filenames.

Comment: arrayfun is still a loop

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using extractBetween, split, and double with the string datatype:

```
function profFunc

    n = 1E4;

    str = {'JFK_1_1.TXT';
           'JFK_12_12.TXT';
           'JFK_123_123.TXT'};

    tic
    for i = 1:n
        A = cellfun(@(x) textscan(x, 'JFK_%d_%d.txt'), str,'UniformOutput', false);
        A = vertcat(A{:});
        A = cell2mat(A);
    end
    toc

    tic
    for i = 1:n
        B = regexp(str,'JFK_(\d*)_(\d*)\.TXT','tokens');
        B = [B{:}];
        B = str2double(vertcat(B{:}));
    end
    toc

    tic
    for i = 1:n
        C = string(str);
        C = extractBetween(C,'_','.');
        C = split(C,'_');
        C = double(C);
    end
    toc

    assert(isequal(A,B,C));
end

>> profFunc
Elapsed time is 1.895104 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.655958 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.094432 seconds.
```